# Twig: Javascript encode a big block of HTML

Tags: twig

I want to JavaScript-encode [sic] a big block of HTML so that I can use it as a template in various places. Something like this would be ideal:

```
var template = {% jsencode %}
<input type="text" value="{{ value }}"/>
{% endjsencode %};
```

The output I would expect is:

```
var template = "\n    <input type=\"text\" value=\"xxx\"/>\n   ";
```

Is there a plugin that will do this?

Comment: It should be jsonencode and you might use it with php

Comment: @gco Twig has a `|json_encode` filter. It doesn't work blocks AFAIK. Edit: Nevermind, you *can* apply filters to a block. Thanks for giving me the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize there was a [`{% filter %}` tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/filter.html). This makes it easy:

```
var x = {% filter json_encode|raw -%}
        <input type="text" value="{{ 5*3 }}"/>
{%- endfilter %};
```

output:

```
var x = "<input type=\"text\" value=\"15\"\/>";
```

Alternatively, you can stuff an entire file in there:

```
var template = {% filter json_encode(constant('JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES'))|raw %}{% include 'bookings/address.twig' %}{% endfilter %};
```